# Unable to replace Universal Image Loader functions with Gllide

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-glide

Universal Image Loader has some methods to load image on main thread but Glide always load image on other thread.
While using Universal library, I can get Drawable directly through cache but in Glide I am doing this,

```
public Drawable fun(){
Drawable blurredImage=null;
RequestOptions options=new RequestOptions();
                options.onlyRetrieveFromCache(true);

                Glide.with(mContext).load(url).apply(options).into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                        blurredImage=resource;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        blurredImage=null;
                    }
                });
return blurredImage;
}
```

Now, this function always returns null because Glide is working on other thread and will call OnResourceReady with some lag.
I want to wait for the function to intialize blurredImage before calling return statement;
I was thinking to use wait(),notify() here but unable to understand how.

Comment: You don't want to block your main thread. Find a way to deal with the asynchronous response. I.e. do whatever needs to be done with `blurredImage` in your `onResourceReady` method.

Comment: I know this is the last option. But the project is quite large and I am supposed to work this way only.

Comment: It is the **right** option. Freezing your UI is not acceptable.

Comment: I totally understand and respect your views and I know its not a good practice.But if it was possible, I haven't asked this in first place.